# Coherence results

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

As far a I know, there are two kinds of results which are called 'coherence theorems'. For bicategories they take approximately the following forms:

1. Every diagram of a certain form commutes
2. A Bicategory is equivalent to a 2-catagory.

This second form seems to be more used than the first, however I am wondering what is the general relationship between those two things. Specifically:

- (2) is false when applied to tricategories. Do we know something about (1)?
- (2) also holds for pseudo-fonctors. Does it hold for pseudo-natural transformations? What about (1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your (1) is usually the key lemma used to prove (2).** When you do higher category theory, you will not necessarily have commuting diagrams anymore, though, but they will only commute up to a canonical isomorphism which itself satisfies some axioms.

What do you mean by "(2) is false when applied to tricategories"? Yes, it's false that tricategories are equivalent to strict 3-categories, and there are good reasons for it. One wouldn't expect them to be equivalent. However, there are other coherence theorems for them, for example every tricategory is equivalent to a [Gray category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gray-category), that's a result by Gordon, Power and Street. And I'd expect that the proof goes again like showing that diagrams involving unit laws commute on the nose in the Gray category and those involving interchange of horizontal and vertical composition commute up to some specific isomorphism, the "interchanger".

Comment: In the case of bicategories, the two results can be deduced from each other, and it is possible to prove (2) whithout using (1). (for exemple there http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9810017).

Concerning tricategories, what I meant is that tricategories are not equivalent to 3-categories. I have tried reading the article you mentioned (and Nick Gurski's thesis), and I think it is more complicated than looking at which diagram commutes, but I do not have a good enough understanding of it to be sure.

Comment: @skysurf3000, Right, so there exist other proofs than going through talking about all the diagrams that occur. But as Leinster writes, usually (1) is an easy consequence of (2) since in a strict category all coherence laws are trivially true. In the same way, I expect that you can translate all the coherence laws holding on the nose in Gray categories (the unit laws) to coherence laws in tricategories.

Comment: I completely agree with what you say about unit laws. My question was motivated by the fact that when defining Gray-categories as enriched categories (as done in the nLab), there doesn't seem to be any coherence isomorphisms. So I was wondering if that meant that all coherence laws hold in a Gray-category, and hence in a tricategory. Another way to express this idea would be that the interchange of horizontal and vertical composition cannot be expressed as a diagram.

Comment: @skysurf3000, I'm not sure I understand you completely, but the interchanger is _the_ coherence isomorphism in a Gray category. It comes as a part of the structure, it's the 2-morphism in the monoidal product of the category $\mathrm{Gray}$, which we are enriching in. So the interchange of horizontal and vertical composition can be expressed as a diagram, in fact a canonical one with this morphism in it. But it's not a diagram involving only objects, morphisms and 2-morphisms, one needs the 3-morphism as well.

Comment: You are right of course. I hadn't thought about the fact that some of the coherence data was hidden in the tensor product.